# How to set size of column of csv file?

Tags: php, excel

I want to set the size of each column in csv file, I want to set the size of column against the field, I don't know where I can do the code of to set the size? Can anyone help it will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
function export($result)
{   
    Configure::write('debug',0);
    $filename = "excel.".csv";
    $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');    

    // The column headings of  .csv file
    $header_row1 = array(   
                        "Last Name",
                        "First Name",
                        "Middle Name",
                        );

    $header_row =   array_merge($header_row1,$header_row2);
    fputcsv($csv_file,$header_row,',','"');

    // Array indexes correspond to the field names in your db table(s)
    if (!isset($result['Post']['User'])) {
        $row1 = array(
            $result['Post']['prefix_name'],
            $result['Post']['first_name'],
            $result['Post']['middle_name'],
            $result['Post']['last_name'],
        );
    }
    else {
            $row1 = array(
            $result['Post']['prefix_name'],
            $result['Post']['first_name'],
            $result['Post']['middle_name'],
            $result['Post']['last_name'],
        );
    }

    $row = array_merge($row1,$row2);

    unset($row2);
    fputcsv($csv_file,$row,',','"');
}

    fclose($csv_file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by CSV column size? The size is what the content is before the delimiter...?

Comment: "Column", the word you are looking for is "Column". Curious, because the "CS" in "CSV" stand for "Comma-separated", thus not sure what column size has to do here.

Comment: There is no limit or Column as such in CSV file. You might be viewing from Excel point of view. You can set limit for the data in your code by defining constants.

Comment: You cannot tag it 1.3 and 2.x - please state your exact version and stick to it.

Comment: but i want to fit the field in column how can i fit that in this structure?

Comment: Either use DOM attributes in HTML or in PHP use constants to truncate/fit data in your limits.

Comment: at inferix.com we use a number is square brackets at the end of the "title words" (of each column) - your code would read that number - but not print it - it would then make that column be that number of "characters" wide - so this is dynamic csv file defined column widths - which is fun - so on the first line (by convention the column/data headings line)......

Comment: .... you woud put NAME[26] as the first "column" if you wanted that name column to be 26 "characters" wide - so the data alters the column size and not the program - you still have to program that reading process into your code - we use DOM "div"s as previously suggested - and we assume 10 pixels per "chatracter" - easy peasy - you can make as complicated a "protocol" as you wish as there is not a fully defined csv file protocol - which is fine > becasue for fast bespoke appications custon csv files are way faster than using databases (MySQL et all) ...

Comment: ... simply becasue there are no database overheads - if you want the fastest csv "database" just pre-index (index sort) the data as it is entered - so that it is already "sorted" on retreval - even if the csv file is huge - so good luck - use CSV files and customise them to your needs - you will be the winner !

Comment: PS > the only way of going even faster and bigger (for planet population size or scientific data) is to keep that same CSV "idea" but make it "binary packed" (e.g as packed binary values) and then encrypted to your liking - it's best NOT TO EVER USE "standards" for either encryption or packing - i.e. why leave your back door open !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't... a CSV file has no formatting of any kind, including column size.

If you want to control column widths, then you need to write the data to a format that does support columns widths, such as BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) or OASIS Open Document Format (.ods) or Gnumeric or other spreadsheet.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this.
CSV stands for [coma separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> A comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and
>   text) in plain-text form. Plain text means that the file is a sequence
>   of characters, with no data that has to be interpreted instead, as
>   binary numbers. A CSV file consists of any number of records,
>   separated by line breaks of some kind; each record consists of fields,
>   separated by some other character or string, most commonly a literal
>   comma or tab. Usually, all records have an identical sequence of
>   fields.

Short and clear definition.
CSV is too primitive for this.
Did you ever try to open CSV file with usual text editor?
You need XLS for this case.

Answer (score 4):

As I know, you cannot set a column size in CSV because there is absolutely no information about the presentation layout. CSV is Coma Separated Value.

The best behaviour for you application that will open your file is to set the column width to fit the data.

If you want to manage your presentation layout, you should instead generate a html content that could be opened with Excel (in example). In such a content, you will be able to set some attributes like `width="400"`...