# PHP write csv file merge headers

Tags: php, csv

```
$file_format = "testfile.csv";
$file = fopen($file_format,"w");

$header = array(array('Class Name','Group'));

foreach($header as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($file, $fields);
}

fclose($file);
```

My question is how do I merge  the group cells as image below?
[image]

Comment: what does the csv look like now and what do you want it to look like after ?

Comment: Can't do anything without seeing a sample of the data... (*as Dagon said above*)

Comment: csv is a data exchange format and can't control the formatting of cells in excel

Answer (score 1):

> You can't... a CSV file has no formatting of any kind, including
>   column size.
>
> If you want to control column widths, then you need to write the data
>   to a format that does support columns widths, such as BIFF (.xls) or
>   OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) or OASIS Open Document Format (.ods) or Gnumeric
>   or other spreadsheet.

From [How to set size of column of csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224052/how-to-set-size-of-column-of-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the data then you can use the PHP libraries for handling CSV data link [this](https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/wiki/Examples)

but if you need to show the well formatted data then you need to use the .xls file. There are lots of libraries which allows you to handle .xls data. Hope this will help you out.