# Excel - Autofit excluding the first row

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file that I have opened in Excel (the CSV is programmatically produced).

I want to autofit the columns so they take up as much row as they need to, but I don't want autofit to be applied to the first row (I want it to be ignored in the autofit calculation).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Just select rows from2 to till last data row then double click on any row border from left where excel is showing row numbers.

Comment: See [How to set size of column of csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224109/924299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column width usually remains constant for all the rows so if you apply autofit from row 2 onwards, the width of the column for row 1 will be same as row 2.